# Help with Evaluating a Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the difference quotient $$\frac { f(a+h)-f(a) }{ h } ,\quad where\quad h\neq 0$$

for the function: $$f(x)=\frac { x }{ x+1 }$$

Steps that I took to try and solve this:

$$\frac { \frac { a+h }{ a+h+1 } -\frac { a }{ a+1 }  }{ h } $$

Denominator became:
$$\frac { (a+h)(a+1)-(a)(a+h+1) }{ (a+h+1)(a+1) } $$

Then,
$$\frac { (a^{ 2 }+a+ah+h)-(a^{ 2 }+ah+a) }{ (a+h+1)(a+1) } $$

Perform subtraction in the numerator and then multiply by reciprocal:
$$\frac { h }{ (a+h+1)(a+1) } *\frac { h }{ 1 } $$

Which becomes: 
$$\frac { h^{ 2 } }{ (a+h+1)(a+1) } $$

This answer is incorrect because the textbook answer key states that the numerator should be a $1$. 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you multiplying by $\frac{h}{1}$? You should devide by $h$ at this point.

Comment: You don't divide by $\frac{1}{h}$ but by $h$, so you don't multiply with the reciprocal, you divide (the numerator) by $h$.

Comment: But division is multiplication by the reciprocal, no?
Oh shoot. I think I just noticed what I was doing wrong. I was multiplying by $h$ rather than by it's reciprocal.

Comment: are you sure it should not be that $a = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(x+h)(x+1) - x(x+h+1) = (x+h)(x+1)-x(x+h) - x = (x+h)-x = h$

Comment: Isn't that what I did with the numerator between the 3rd and 4th steps? I ended up with $h$

Comment: OK sorry I didn't notice this. You should multiply this result by $\frac{1}{h}$ and take $a=0, h=0$ to get the result of $1$, which is essentially the definition of the derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: So then the mistake was as I suspected? I multiplied by $h$ rather than it's reciprocal?

Comment: divide by $h$ = multiply by $\frac{1}{h}$, but to get the textbook result you need to do more

Comment: so then the denominator becomes $(a+h+1)(a+1)(h)$ and the numerator is just $h$. Cancel the $h's$ out?

Answer (score 0):

In the last step it is division by h, not multiplication, i.e. The last step should be $\frac{h}{h(a+h+1)(a+1)}$. So the h get cancelled. My suggestion would be not to divide the calculation into numerator and denominator like you did, that seems to have caused the confusion. Do your calculation of the numerator keeping the h in the denominator.